# need to remove horizontal border from the tbar menu

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, tbar

I have a bunch of tbar items displayed in new lines. It works fine.
But the only issue I am having is that displays a horizontal border between each tbars.
How can I remove that?

```
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    id: 'navi',
                    region: 'west',
                    collapsible: false,
                    title: 'Navigation',
                    bodyStyle: 'background-color: #BFCBD5',
                    width: 155,
                    animCollapse: true,
                    minHeight: 600,
                    items: [

                        {
                            border:0,

                            tbar: [

                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    text: 'Home',
                                    textAlign:'left',
                                    width: 140,
                                    align:'left',

                                    //bodyStyle: 'background-color:#BFCBD5;',
                                    handler: function() {
                                        document.location.href = BasePath; 
                                    }
                                }


                            ]
                        },

                        {
                            border:0,
                            tbar: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    text: 'Dashboard',
                                    textAlign:'left',
                                    width: 140,                                     
                                    handler: function() {
                                        document.location.href="http://www.dtvdashboard.com";
                                    }
                                }                                   

                            ]
                        },  



                    {
                        xtype: 'text',
                        padding: '64 0 0 0',    
                        text: "Logged in as:",
                        textAlign:'left',
                        style : "color:#3E546B;font-style:italic;font-size: 11px;",
                        width: 140,
                        handler: function() {
                            document.location.href="";
                        }
                    },  




                    ]


                }
            ]
```

EDIT: I added bodyBorder:false, that kinda removed the border line. But i still see lighter shade of the border

[image]

Comment: You might want to crop the image and re-upload that cropped image. That white-space is entirely irrelevant to the question, and distracts from the part you (presumably) want people to look at. And, really, an image is not the best demonstration of a problem in JavaScript; you might want to post a (minimal/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) live [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo that we can see in action and work with easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is plenty of possibilities to remove that border.

- you can remove tbar and stick to the buttons only (example: http://jsfiddle.net/kKjuC/1/)
- you can render links as plain html and attach click handler to each one or to the container or just simply add `href` to links (example: http://jsfiddle.net/YeyET/1/)
- you can use DataView